# Respect labels spacing

Tags: uitableview, swift2, uilabel, uistoryboard

Working with a UITableViewController. You can see my prototype cell in the screenshot; It's made up by 2 labels (1 on the left containing quantity X item name, and 1 on the right with the price).

When the left label is too long (or when testing on a 3.5" device), there's no space left between the 2 labels and they enter each other's space. How can I make sure that when they get really close to each other, I show something like "1 X item n..." instead of "1 X item name" so that there's always some space between the 2?

I am using auto-layout by the way (with a spacing constraint between them but it doesn't seem to respect it).

Hope I am making sense!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, just got it. Had to decrease content hugging.

Comment: Would you provide the code example for how you set constraints, if you set them programmatically?

Comment: i set them via SB, sorry. but the idea is a single spacing constraint between the 2, and decreased content hugging for the one on the left. SnapKit seems like a good alternative also.